# Displaying cart codeigniter from newest added first

Tags: php, codeigniter, cart

This is my code:

```
$cart = $this->cart->contents();
foreach ($cart as $item){

}
```

How to display cart from newest added first?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array_reverse function

```
$reversed_cart = array_reverse($cart);
```